# Numbers ending with j

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I tried to compute the eigenvectors of a matrix with scipy. The results where some numbers like this one: `-3.47686396e-01+0.j`. What does the `j` stand for and mean? i.e. how to interpret this number?!

Also how to make convert/print it in usual format i.e. -1.00 or something like this. The format usually known.

Comment: I don't know what `scipy` is (scientific python?) but `j` is often used by electronic engineers as an alternative to the mathematician's `i` -- that is the square-root of `-1`.  In other words, it's a purely real number (`0.347...`) with no complex/imaginary part

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Numbers with `j` are [complex numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#complex):

```
>>> 1j * 1j
(-1+0j)
```

You can extract real part and imaginary part using `real`, `imag` attributes:

```
>>> c = 1 + 2j
>>> c.real
1.0
>>> c.imag
2.0
```

---

To convert numpy array with complex numbers to array with float: same; use `real`, `imag` attributes.

```
>>> np.array([1+0j, 2+0j]).real
array([ 1.,  2.])
```

Comment: I have a matrix full with complex numbers then, how to format all of the numbers in once?